# to print a session using ajax codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my page

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>total',
            data:'id=1',
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('.searc_res').show();
            },
            success:function(html){
                $('.searc_res').remove();
                $('.searc_res').append(html);
            }
        });
    });
```

This is just to return in the div the value of a session 
Session is: `$this->session->userdata('searchItems_Total')`

How to do this in the `total.php` file?
Do I need to create something in the `model`?

Comment: why do u need to ajax to print session , instead do it like as u do for ajax url , like this : `var session = '<?=$this->session->userdata('searchItems_Total');?>';
    $('.searc_res').append(session);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just print it?

```
public function total()
{
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    /.../
    echo json_encode($this->session->userdata('searchItems_Total'));
}
```

In your client side call (to view the returned data's structure):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp); 
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Kisaragi, I'm having the 404 `class TotalTabela extends CI_Controller {

    function index(){
        $this->load->library("session"); 

  echo $this->session->userdata('searchItems_Total');
 }
}` I just want to echo the session, do I need to create something in viewes or models?

Answer (score 0):

You can just `return $this->session->userdata('item');` in your php function or you can just `echo` the values in your html since you are trying send an ajax request in document ready state which is not necessary.